# How can 'default' be the default value in swift?

Tags: swift

I recognized that 'default' is the default value in Apple's Dispatch API:

`public class func global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass = default) -> DispatchQueue`

However, when I try to declare a function myself using 'default' as the default value it fails.

So I'm wondering how 'default' is defined here.

Comment: Show your code where you have tried that.

Comment: if you observe argument type is QoSClass which is enum and default is a one of  the case in enum. see here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos.qosclass   and it is example of method with default value so `default` is default value of function in case if you not provide any argument to `qos`

Comment: Although it's an enumeration, you can't use **default** as a default value. Try it yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing that you will see when you look at the generated header files.

The header files does not contain actual compilable code. Their main use is to tell you the interface of the API. They don't have the implementation details. You probably can't find any function bodies in that file, right? Because those are implementation details.

The same goes for `= default`. It indicates that this argument is optional, and that it has some kind of default value. You don't need to care what it is.

Another example of this is:

```
public func split(maxSplits: Int = default, omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = default, whereSeparator isSeparator: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [ArraySlice<Element>]
```

in `Array`.

Comment: It can only be used by Apple, we can't.

Comment: If you view the headers of your own code with optional parameters, you will see this as well. @Laughing

Comment: But the type is not optional, like Int, Bool, DispatchQoS.QoSClass in our examples.

Comment: @Laughing the type is not `Optional<T>`. The parameter is optional, as in, you can pass the parameter or not pass the parameter.

Comment: Yes, you're right, optional type and optional parameter are different things. Only optional type is available to us, and optional parameter is reserved by Apple currently.